# Javascript onscroll and mouse position

Tags: javascript, cursor-position, onscroll

I have a script that runs a addEventListener for onmousemove and onscroll on the document body to get the cursor position. A onmousemove event works fine (client + scroll), however when a onscroll event occurs clientX/Y seems to inherit scrollTop/Left values instead (only scroll). Is there a way around this?

```
clickDocument = (document.documentElement != undefined && document.documentElement.clientHeight != 0) ? document.documentElement : document.body;

var posx = 0;
var posy = 0;
if (e.pageX || e.pageY)     {
    posx = e.pageX;
    posy = e.pageY;
}
else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
    posx = e.clientX;
    posy = e.clientY;
}

var scrollx = window.pageXOffset == undefined ? clickDocument.scrollLeft : window.pageXOffset;
var scrolly = window.pageYOffset == undefined ? clickDocument.scrollTop : window.pageYOffset;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the IE browser version and the doctype, sometimes you need `clickDocument.body.scrollTop`
or even `clickDocument.documentElement.scrollTop`.

(Source: http://javascript.about.com/library/blmousepos.htm)

Comment: This is happening in FF and Chrome.